# how to run Flutter application on iOS emulator?

Tags: flutter

im trying to run the app on iOS emulator . the error I get is this :

```
Xcode's output:

Writing result bundle at path:
    /var/folders/s3/16z94fvx7sb0gsfm3rngxrtc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.c8pxkF/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirCqRXDZ/temporar
    y_xcresult_bundle

../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:2
5: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to package /Users/admin/Downloads/revocheck2-app-develop.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Building targets in dependency order
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any
outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in
every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project
'Runner')
warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any
outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in
every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project
'Runner')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/s3/16z94fvx7sb0gsfm3rngxrtc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.c8pxkF/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirCqRXDZ/temporar
    y_xcresult_bundle
```

does anyone have a solution? thanks

Comment: what version of firebase are you using in pubspec.yaml, try updating it to latest

Comment: hi . there 3 are in my pubspec:    firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.2.1
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core, https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics, https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging, try to use latest one

Comment: Google it for "Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'". The very first link shows the solution.